# Firebase authenticated user but no permission

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following rule:

```
rules": {
    ".read": "( auth.token.email.matches(/.*@domain1.com$/) || auth.token.email.matches(/.*@domain2.com$/) || auth.token.email.matches(/.*@domain3.com$/) ) && auth.token.email_verified == true",
    ".write": "( auth.token.email.matches(/.*@domain1.com$/) || auth.token.email.matches(/.*@domain2.com$/) || auth.token.email.matches(/.*@domain3.com$/) ) && auth.token.email_verified == true"
}
```

I am trying to use firebase realtime database rule playground to test why after the user is authenticated on my app, any call to the firebase realtime returns the error:

```
permission_denied at /anyDocument: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

My database does not have any permission by document, as long as the user is authenticated, they should have access to any and all documents within it. I am using the below auth payload:"

```
{
  "uid": "",
  "token": {
    "sub": "",
    "aud": "keane-docc-dev",
    "email": "email@domain1.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "password"
    }
  }
}
```

On the rule simulation, it works, but on the app I get the error of permission.

My login code is:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

export class SignInComponent {
signIn(email: string, password: string) {    
    this.angularFireAuth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // I do some stuff here
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.authErrorHandler(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Everything works, user is authenticated, token id matches what is expected, but permission fails.

On my app.component I use the standard method to initialize. I am using [angular/fire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire) and initialize the module as per docs. Any ideas what I am missing?

EXTRA INFO:
Some other Questions in here points that the user may not be authenticated by the time the realtime database query is executed. I think this is hardly my case, because once I authenticate on firebase, I use that token to authenticate with a API that uses the firebase token to check who is my user, and that token is checked back by the API with the Firebase SDK to firebase (my project runs on GCP).

All of this started because I am no longer using ngx-auth-firebaseui, that package once did my firebase initialize and now I am using AngularFire, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was related to outdated versions of firebase and angular/fire. They would query, authenticate, but fail on the rule. Probably there was a new version with an object change of the payload.

Once I update both, the error went away.